# Google Sheets Query - Group by more than one column without a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a timesheet dataset containing 4 columns:

Column 1 - A workers name

Column 2 - The date they worked

Column 3 - The project they worked on

Column 4 - The hours they worked on that date, on that project.

Eg

[image]

I'm just starting to learn about the QUERY function and I hope it is possible to group the lines by two columns - Name and Date - and sum the hours, regardless of the Project, worked on each date, and end up with a table like this:

[image]

So far I've just learned how to group by a single columns values.  I'm not looking for a pivot table (at least I don't think I am) because I need to be able to use the resulting table to compare with another table (attendance data) and I think it will be easier if I keep the timesheet records on a single line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by more than one columns in a query. You do not need a pivot table for that.
On the other hand, when using pivot in your query, the results will be presented in different ways.

#### Without a pivot

```
=QUERY(A1:D9, "select A, B, sum(D) group by A, B label sum(D) 'Hours' ",1)
```

[image: Google Sheets query, sum, group by 2 columns]

#### Using a pivot

```
=QUERY(A1:D9, "select B, sum(D) group by A pivot B label sum(D) 'Hours' ",1)
```

OR

```
=QUERY(A1:D9, "select B, sum(D) group by B pivot A label sum(D) 'Hours' ",1)
```

[image: Google Sheets query, sum, group by, pivot]

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, and thanks for providing the correct answer @marikamitsos

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Comment: Note that the two formulas under "Using a pivot" are identical. I think that in the first line `group by B pivot A` is meant to be `group by A pivot B`.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @AnthonyHolland. It is now fixed.