# Google Sheets Pivot Table take first string

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet of many-to-many matches between people. My data looks something like this:

```
+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| id1 | name1 | id2 | name2 |
+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| 123 | John  | 456 | Jane  |
| 123 | John  | 789 | Bob   |
| 456 | Jane  | 999 | Susan |
| 111 | John  | 888 | Roger |
+-----+-------+-----+-------+
```

I've created a pivot table in order to see the number of matches per person (matches are directed and I only care about id1 -> id2 edges).
My problem is, because people can have the same name, I need to use id as the primary key in the pivot table. But if I do that I can't easily see which name the id corresponds to. I tried taking the "minimum" of each name in my pivot table, but then I just get the number `0`. I just want to take an arbitrary name from any of the matches. Is this possible?

This is my desired output format:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+
| id1 | name1 | match_count |
+-----+-------+-------------+
| 123 | John  |           2 |
| 456 | Jane  |           1 |
| 111 | John  |           1 |
+-----+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that output create pivot, add id1 and name1 as Rows, tick off totals (unnecessary)
and add name1 to Values with COUNTA formula
[image: Pivot]

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following formula:

```
=QUERY({B2:C;D2:E}, 
     "select Col1,Col2, count(Col1) 
      where Col1 is not null group by Col1, Col2 label count(Col1) ''")
```

[image: Query formula]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question is specific to pivot tables. I guess it can't be done with them?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Glad you worked it out. I still don't understand though why you reverted my edit on it. Is your data on a single column separated by commas? You can also have a look at [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138313).

Comment: I reverted because I only wanted directed edges, not undirected as in your edit. And then I was just too lazy to add the table syntax back, haha.

Comment: _"...was just too lazy..."_> Totally understand that :) The `,` was what threw me off though. If you find some time, you could probably edit using this [ASCII Tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) site. Keep everything on default. You write what you want as a range in your sheet, copy, paste on the site. Copy, paste on the question here. Done

Comment: Cool, yeah that works.